# SoapUI IP requester

Tags: soapui

In order to implement a simple soapui asynchronous response pattern, I need to retrieve the IP of the client that sent the initial request to be able to send the response back to the correct requester.

I can not find a way to retrieve this info from the request using the soapui mock request API, was wondering if anyone has a trick to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it is actually really easy when you look at the good class. I was looking at the interface `com.eviware.soapui.model.mock.MockRequest` instead of the implementation `com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockRequest`

With the implementation this will provide the response
`mockRequest.getHttpRequest().getRemoteAddr()`

Hope this helps anyone else!